# exposing .net events using ironpython

Tags: ironpython

I'm implementing a .net class in ironpython and the class needs to expose some .net events.

How do I expose .net events using ironpython?

I checked out the Tutorial\pyevent.py, but the procedure seems complicated for exposing a single event. is there any key words in iron python that would let me do this.

regards
G

Answer (score 2):

It isn't difficult utilizing pyevent.py - see [my blog](http://gui-at.blogspot.com/2009/11/inotifypropertychanged-in-ironpython.html) post where I implement *OnPropertyChanged* event.

You can find details about events in [IronPython documentation](http://ironpython.net/documentation/dotnet/).